# Can someone boot my OS using a different motherboard?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, motherboard

A tech support person fixing my laptop told me that the laptop's motherboard is damaged. At the same time, he called me and requested the Windows password so that he can access the computer.

Is there any contradiction in this story? If he changes the motherboard to a new one and connects it to my old hard drive, is it possible to access the OS on the hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if he change the motherboard with new one and connect it with my old hard drive, Is it possible to access the old windows ?

**Short answer: Yes**

I have swapped out a motherboard and been able to access the Windows install that was on the hard disk in the system prior to the motherboards.

In hundreds of cases, I have advised technicians I was supervising to swap out motherboards as well. 
In all cases where the existing hard drive was not damaged prior to my technician arriving on the customer premises, the Windows install was accessible once the failed motherboard was replaced.

The only possible hang-ups I can see would be if the motherboard was not very similar to the old one and your system's Windows install was under an OEM license. In cases like this, you or your technician may need to contact Microsoft for assistance with activation. In certain 
circumstances, you may need to purchase a new license.

Unless you have been advised that there is to be a licensing issue, it is reasonable to assume that there will be no such issue.

Comment: Even if the hardware was different. There are ways to boot to entirely new hardware using an existing Windows installation. You basically have to remove all the drivers from being loaded.  Of course this doesn't explain why the password is required, the fact Windows was able to get to that point, proves the installation is working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's absolutely possible, and incredibly likely. The only thing that might prevent it would be some sort of drive encryption software. Barring that, hard drives are pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: but the booting information and parameters for the windows are stored in the last motherboard' bios, how could he access the windows in the new motherboard without booting informaiton stored on it ?

Comment: That info isn't stored in BIOS. It's stored on disk.

Comment: @cpast when the cpu start booting and loading the operation system , he read the contents of a specific memory address that is preprogrammed into the CPU.  In the case of x86 based processors, this address is FFFF:0000h. 
The code that the processor reads is actually a jump command (JMP) telling the processor where to go in memory to read the BIOS ROM.
after loading the bios info, he goes to read from disk

Comment: @oofy And? Your point?

Comment: the booting info for the windows is stored in the bios. and i changed the motherboard that has new bios, how could i access the last windows ?

Comment: That booting info is *not* in the BIOS. Read my answer; anything that's needed to boot is the same on all computers.

Comment: Bootloaders have been standard for many years (think decades) and all BIOS that I am aware of is able to find the primary bootloader on the hard drive... @oofy, you are speaking about a secondary bootloader, which is stored on the drive. The primary bootloader will locate and run it. No worries. This happens all the time.

Comment: @oofy You are seeing one reason why this is done - it's _really_ convenient to be able to boot any hard drive in any computer. Recovery would be almost impossible otherwise.

Comment: @oofy - Your information is not entirely correct as other people point out.  The information is not stored in the CPU ( the CPU can't store anything ) nor the BIOS, all the information needed to boot ANY x86-64 operating system exists in the boot loader sector of your hdd.

Answer (score 0):

A motherboard, while essential to run the computer, doesn't store much of anything. The only information contained on the motherboard, in fact, is technical elements of the hardware configuration (and the clock). Everything else goes on the hard drive; in fact, it is possible to take a hard drive out of one computer, put it in a different one, boot the second one, and use it with no issues at all. I have actually done this (when a server died, I removed the disks and put them in a different server); while there are minor things that may not work, almost everything works fine.

Specifically, the reason this is possible is that a lot of work goes into standardizing things so that it is possible. There is a standard way to store bootloaders; every motherboard knows how this works, and so can boot from any hard drive.

Comment: You can do this with all operating systems.  In most cases operating systems are installed and configured to load certain drivers, this often can cause problems, even with Unix and Linux although in those cases there are easier to resolve.